# 2sxc - How To create toolbar button to open custom CSHTML

Tags: 2sxc

If I want to create a button for template-editor I am using this code:

```
@Edit.Toolbar(actions: "template-develop")
```

But in my template code I also use code like this:

```
@RenderPage("_pager.cshtml", new { count = data.pCount, active = data.pActive})
```

And if I want to edit this file: **_pager.cshtml** I have to go to the server with FTP or RDP and change this file...

Can I and how create **"template-editor"** button for _pager.cshtml that I can edit it inside web browser?

Comment: I would like to know if this is possible as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wonder why you need to open it through FTP or RDP as you can edit it directly from website by clicking the template name :
[image]

Comment: Thanks, did not know this.

Comment: I accepted this question but it would be nice to do this with the edit button.

Comment: ATM the code-editor could use a lot more love, we just don't have the resources for that.